# Fixed background image, that doesn't move when new views are loaded

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app with a navigation controller. Views slide in from the right. I want a background picture that is fixed, so that it doesn't slide with the views pushed on the nav controller. Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to, for example, add a UIImageView with your background image as a subview of your app's UIWindow, underneath the UINavigationController's view. Then set the background color of each UIViewController to [UIColor clearColor], and the static background image should show through.

Comment: This worked very well in iOS 5. Thank you. Somehow it doesn't work in iOS 6. I get the standard gray grouped style backround. Any ideas?

Comment: Found a very simple solution. I had to set the following property in viewdidload for each tableview, to make the background come through:     myTableView.backgroundView=nil; Credit to this guy https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/821